# Visibility Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a form box appear from being hidden. I've set it hidden with `<input type="text" id="elemBox" name="elemBox4" class="element" hidden="hidden"/>`.

How would I make it visible using a javascript function?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider accepting one of the answers

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
<input type="text" id="elemBox" name="elemBox4" class="element" style="display:none" />
```

Or, the better way to hide it would be to write `display:none` in your CSS file:

```
.element {
    display: none;
}
```

Show the element via JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("#elemBox").style.display = "block";
```

Hide it again:

```
document.querySelector("#elemBox").style.display = "none";
```

You can also use `document.getElementById` if you'd like instead of `querySelector`.

Answer (score 2):

you can make a textbox hidden using

- type=hidden
- visibility:hidden--Element will not be visible,but occupies some space on the dom
- Display:none--Element will not be visible and does not occupy any space

If you make it as type=hidden,want to make it visible ,you can just remove the attribute
please check the following snippet

```js
window.onload=function(){
var element=document.getElementById('elemBox');
element.removeAttribute('type');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="elemBox" name="elemBox4" class="element" type="hidden"/>
```

Hope it helps